# Distilbert Autotokenizer for custom data:: TypeError: PreTokenizedEncodeInput must be Union[PreTokenizedInputSequence, T

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize, huggingface-tokenizers, distilbert

I am new to distillbert and want to use it for token classification. I have my own dataset and own class labels. Used the following function to tokenize.

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("distilbert-base-uncased")
label_all_tokens=True
def tokenize_and_align_labels(examples):
    tokenized_inputs = tokenizer(examples["tokens"], truncation=True, 
                                 is_split_into_words=True, padding=True)
    labels = []
    for i, label in enumerate(examples['ner_tags']):
        word_ids = tokenized_inputs.word_ids(batch_index=i)
        previous_word_idx = None
        label_ids = []
        for word_idx in word_ids:
            # Special tokens have a word id that is None. We set the label to -100 so they are automatically
            # ignored in the loss function.
            if word_idx is None:
                label_ids.append(-100)
            # We set the label for the first token of each word.
            elif word_idx != previous_word_idx:
                label_ids.append(label[word_idx])
            # For the other tokens in a word, we set the label to either the current label or -100, depending on
            # the label_all_tokens flag.
            else:
                label_ids.append(label[word_idx] if label_all_tokens else -100)
            previous_word_idx = word_idx

        labels.append(label_ids)

    tokenized_inputs["labels"] = labels
    return tokenized_inputs
```

getting this error:

> TypeError: PreTokenizedEncodeInput must be Union[PreTokenizedInputSequence, Tuple[PreTokenizedInputSequence, PreTokenizedInputSequence]]

it would be great if any one could provide help. Thanks

image for full error https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP4J6.jpg

Comment: Could you include the full error please?

Comment: @Thomas, added as image..

Comment: Please include the **full** stack trace, in your post directly

Comment: Try using tokenizer.tokenize() instead of tokenizer() due to your dataset.